# Attach metadata to thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there any way to attach some kind of custom metadata(any object) to the thread in java? For example if I run couple of threads using ThreadPoolExecutor with some attached to each metadata and pass these threads into some processor which will be able to read this metadata?

As far as I see from the source code of the Thread, the only thing I can do - just set thread name.

Thanks to AlexR I've solved the problem. That one remember's Id of the thread which launches this thread.

```
public class StarterThreadAwareThread extends Thread {

    private volatile long startedThreadId;

    public StarterThreadAwareThread(ThreadGroup group, Runnable target, String name) {
        super(group, target, name);
    }

    public long getStartedThreadId() {
        return startedThreadId;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void start() {
        this.startedThreadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        super.start();
    }
}
```

Then some magic with ThreadFactory - overriding the creation of the new thread

```
Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
    return new StarterThreadAwareThread(getThreadGroup(), runnable, nextThreadName());
}
```

And then in each place we can access statically to the submitter's thread id like

```
StarterThreadAwareThread thread = (StarterThreadAwareThread)Thread.currentThread(); // check with instaneof before casting if required
thread.getStartedThreadId();
```

PS: this solution works, if ThreadPoolExecutor creates new thread each time you call submit. If not, I've created more complicated solution but it should work always and everywhere:
1. http://pastebin.com/GU4S793Y
2. http://pastebin.com/f936R2rc
3. http://pastebin.com/YxuGXHiT

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you try to achieve. Why would the metadata of a `Thread` be relevant if you use an executor? You could try `ThreadLocal`, or a map from `Thread` to the metadata, but I find it hard to imagine a use case.

Comment: The main aim I'm longing to, is ability to get the If of the thread which has sumbitted the task into ThreadPoolExecutor.
If case I create thread manually, I can use just parent thread id. But in case ThreadPoolExecutor drives thread creation and reusing, I can't easily get id of the thread which has sumbitted the task.
For examople I've got a special logger appender, which has to log traces only for special thread and all subthreads. Since threads, launched by ThreadPoolExecutor are not children threads, it is hard to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the easiest way to implement this in your case is using custom thread factory and your own thread implementation.

Create `MetadataAwareThread`:

```
public class MetadataAwareThread extends Thread {
    MetadataAwareThread(Runnable runnable, Map<String, String> metadata) {}
}
```

Now create your custom thread factory:

```
public class MetadataAwareThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
     return new MetadataAwareThread(r, new HashMap<String, String>());
   }
}
```

Now you can use this factory as following:

`Exectors.newCachedThreadPool(new MetadataAwareThreadFactory())`

Answer (score 0):

Attach the metadata into the `Runnable`  instead. It's not `Threads` you run, `Threads` run `Runnables` (well, `Threads` are also `Runnables`, but they call `Runnable`'s `run()` method).

Answer (score 0):

You could make the constructor of the class that implements the Runnable interface to have some parameters (or use setters on it). You may then use instanceof to see if the object is of a class you know that contains metadata.